# C#/Mono - Issue with memory mapped file

Tags: c#, mono, arm, beagleboneblack

EDIT: I've update mono (had to compile from source using [these instructions](http://neildanson.wordpress.com/2013/12/10/building-mono-on-a-raspberry-pi-hard-float/)) to version 3.2.7.  I am no longer getting an error complaining about the capacity overload argument, now I am getting the error below.  Previously, when using mono verison 2.1, I was able to open a small text file as a memory mapped file as a test.  Using the new version of mono I get this same error no matter what file I am trying to open/which overload arguments supply or leave out.  A quick google search didn't yield anything so I'm turning back to you, stackoverflow.  What should I do?

`Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall ---> System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Mono_Posix_Syscall_get_at_fdcwd
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall:get_at_fdcwd ()
  at Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMapImpl.Open (System.String path, FileMode mode, Int64 capacity, MemoryMappedFileAccess access) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile (System.String path, FileMode mode, System.String mapName, Int64 capacity, MemoryMappedFileAccess access) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile (System.String path) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall ---> System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Mono_Posix_Syscall_get_at_fdcwd
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall:get_at_fdcwd ()
  at Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMapImpl.Open (System.String path, FileMode mode, Int64 capacity, MemoryMappedFileAccess access) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile (System.String path, FileMode mode, System.String mapName, Int64 capacity, MemoryMappedFileAccess access) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile (System.String path) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0`

I am working on a project involving controlling GPIO pins on a beaglebone.  I am trying to port some python code into C# (a language I'm not super familiar with) and have run into an issue trying to open the registers on the board located in /dev/mem as memory mapped files like I did in python.  I am writing and compiling the code in visual studio 2010 with .Net framework version 4.0.30319 and running it in ubuntu using mono with compiler version 2.10.8.1.

The stripped down code is as follows:

```
long offset = 0x4804c000;
long length = 0xfff;
using (var mm0 = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(@"/dev/mem", FileMode.Open, 
                 "gpio1", capacity))
{
    using (var accessor = mm0.CreateViewAccessor(offset, length))
    {
    do stuff
    }
}
```

Which generates the following error:

`Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: capacity
  at System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMapImpl.Open (System.String path, FileMode mode, Int64 capacity, MemoryMappedFileAccess access) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile (System.String path, FileMode mode, System.String mapName, Int64 capacity, MemoryMappedFileAccess access) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile (System.String path, FileMode mode, System.String mapName, Int64 capacity) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ArgumentException: capacity
  at System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMapImpl.Open (System.String path, FileMode mode, Int64 capacity, MemoryMappedFileAccess access) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile (System.String path, FileMode mode, System.String mapName, Int64 capacity, MemoryMappedFileAccess access) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile (System.String path, FileMode mode, System.String mapName, Int64 capacity) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0`

I've tried specifying and not specifying the capacity of the memory map as well as a lot of different values for the capacity from a couple of megabytes to the entire available ram on the board.  Anyone have tips for where to go from here?

Comment: Does the same error happen if you use the CreateFromFile method which doesn't take a capacity parameter?

Comment: Yes.  Interestingly (or not?) I was able to open a different, much smaller, file without issue so I think it may be something about /dev/mem.

Comment: I just upgraded Mono to 3.2.8 to see if a program works better in it, unfortunately I also get the `System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall ---> System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Mono_Posix_Syscall_get_at_fdcwd` error but mine stems from calling `MessageBox.Show()`

Answer (score 0):

Mono 2.10 is extremely old, please upgrade.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and compile from source.  This was the version available in the ubuntu arm repos.

Comment: Still having issues with mono version 3.2.7 but this does answer the initial question.  Thanks!

Comment: that exception indicates that you installed mono incorrectly